# Merge User fields in Visualforce Email Template

Tags: visualforce, process-builder, email-template, user, email-alert

I am creating a visualforce email template on a custom object. I want to add the Name,Email, and Phone of the User (object) who is sending the email. I have tried both {!relatedTo.User.Name} and {!relatedTo.CreatedById.Name} but none of them works. I get the error 'Error: Unknown property 'String.Name' when I try to save the template.

Comment: did you try `{!$User.Name}` ? ; `relatedTo` references the custom object, not the running user

Answer (score 0):

it should be `{!relatedTo.CreatedBy.Name}`

Please go thru trailhead or Salesforce Documentation to know how to use dot notation.